# Trouble with definition of a lattice: Meaning of finite volume of $\Gamma\setminus G$

Tags: definition, lie-groups, lattices-in-lie-groups

Let $G$ be a Lie group and $\Gamma$ be a discrete subgroup of $G$. Definition 1.3.5 of Dave Witte Morris's *Introduction to Arithmetic Groups* says the following:

> We say that $\Gamma$ is a **lattice** in $G$ if $\Gamma\setminus G$ has finite volume (with respect to the Haar measure on $G$).

I am unable to understand this definition. What is meant by saying "$\Gamma\setminus G$ has finite volume with respect to the Haar measure on $G$?"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A Haar measure on $G$ induces a canonical measure on the coset space $\Gamma\backslash G$.  There are various ways of defining it, but here's probably the simplest: a Haar measure on $G$ can be represented by a left invariant volume form $\omega$, and then you can push that volume form down to $\Gamma\backslash G$ along the quotient map (which is a local diffeomorphism).  The pushforward is well-defined since $\omega$ is left invariant, and in particular invariant under left multiplication by any element of $\Gamma$.

Comment: So this way we can create a nonzero $G$-invariant Radon measure on $\Gamma\setminus G$. But that means that $\Delta_G|_\Gamma=\Delta_\Gamma$, where $\Delta_G$ and $\Delta_\Gamma$ are the modular functions of $G$ and $\Gamma$ respectively. Is there an easy way to see it? Of course, if $G$ is unimodular then this is clear since $\Gamma$ is discrete. But I can't see it directly otherwise. Or am I making a mistake?  Thanks.

Comment: The measure on $\Gamma\backslash G$ is _not_ necessarily $G$-invariant.  This is because $G$ acts on $\Gamma\backslash G$ _on the right_ but the volume form is left-invariant, not right invariant.  The usual definition of "lattice" though requires not only that $\Gamma\backslash G$ has finite volume but also that its measure is $G$-invariant (and so, such a $\Gamma$ can only exist if $G$ is unimodular).

Comment: From a quick glance, it looks like Morris's book always assumes $G$ is semisimple, and thus in particular unimodular.

Comment: I see. The actions are very confusing. Left right left right my mind is exploding.

Answer (score 2):

Let $\Gamma$ be a discrete subgroup of $G$, and let $\mu$ be a right Haar measure on $G$.  Up to scalar multiple, there is a unique Radon measure $\bar{\mu}$ on the quotient space $\Gamma \backslash G$ such that

$$\bar{\mu}(Eg) = \bar{\mu}(E)$$
for all Borel subsets $E \subset \Gamma \backslash G$ and all $g \in G$.  If $f \in C_c(G)$ is a continuous and compactly supported complex valued function, then the averaged function
$$\dot f: \Gamma \backslash G \rightarrow \mathbb C$$

$$\dot f(\Gamma g) = \sum\limits_{\gamma \in \Gamma} f(\gamma g)$$
is well defined and lies in $C_c(\Gamma \backslash G)$. 
 The measure can be scaled so that (with a slight abuse of notation)

$$\int\limits_G f(g)d\mu(g) = \int\limits_{\Gamma \backslash G} \dot f(\Gamma g) d\bar{\mu}(g) = \int\limits_{\Gamma \backslash G} \Bigg(\sum\limits_{\gamma \in \Gamma} f(\gamma g) \Bigg)d\bar{\mu}(g)$$
for all $f \in C_c(G)$.

The **volume** of $\Gamma \backslash G$ is the measure of $\Gamma \backslash G$ with respect to $\bar{\mu}$.  When $\Gamma$ is a lattice, the volume of $\Gamma \backslash G$ of course depends on the normalization of the measures involved.

If $\Gamma \backslash G$ is compact, then $\Gamma$ is automatically a lattice, e.g. $G = \mathbb R$ and $\Gamma = \mathbb Z$.  But there are other examples  where $\Gamma \backslash G$ has finite volume but is not compact, e.g. $G = \operatorname{SL}_2(\mathbb R)$ and $\Gamma = \operatorname{SL}_2(\mathbb Z)$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have the same question I have asked of @EricWofsey. The existence of $\bar \mu$, as far as I know, implies that the restriction of the modular function of $G$ to $\Gamma$ is same as the modular function of $\Gamma$, which is trivial. Can we see this fact directly? Thanks.

Comment: I believe that if a lattice exists for $G$, then $G$ is actually unimodular.

Comment: Yes but we are not guaranteed that a lattice exists. Are we?

Comment: No, because there are non-unimodular groups : P